# Manually Inserting Test Data For Joined Table Inheritance Model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a get_or_create method within a helper class for SQLAlchemy, but the session never returns any data from the query, so a new row is always attempted to be created - even when there is the same data within the database (which then throws a `UNIQUE CONSTRANT` error).

Adding data through the create method on its own does work successfully and data is persisted to the DB. Within the `get_or_create()` method, instance is always `None` and therefore data is attempted to be added to the database again.

Code below is a snippet from full application and should show just enough to replicate the problem.

`models.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Float, Enum
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import enum

Base = declarative_base()


class DepositStatus(enum.Enum):
    not_yet_paid = 1
    paid = 2
    to_be_refunded = 3
    deposit_kept = 4
    refunded = 5


class RiderStatus(enum.Enum):
    not_yet_started = 1
    active = 2
    finished = 3
    scratched = 4


class RiderCategories(enum.Enum):
    solo = 1
    pair = 2


class RiderGenders(enum.Enum):
    male = 1
    female = 2


class TrackerLocations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tracker_locations'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    types = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': types
    }


class Riders(TrackerLocations):

    __tablename__ = 'riders'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tracker_locations.id'), primary_key=True,
                autoincrement=True)
    first_name = Column('first_name', String)
    last_name = Column('last_name', String)
    cap_number = Column('cap_number', String)
    category = Column('category', Enum(RiderCategories))
    status = Column('status', Enum(RiderStatus))
    gender = Column('gender', Enum(RiderGenders))
    deposit_status = Column('deposit_status', Enum(DepositStatus))
    deposit_amount = Column('deposit_amount', Float)
    email = Column('email', String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'riders'
    }
```

`db.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from models import Base

class DB(object):
    """
    To be used to interact with SQLAlchemy's ORM.
    """

    def __init__(self, db_uri):
        self.engine = create_engine(db_uri)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self._session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine))

    def close(self):
        self.session.close()

    def rollback(self):
        self.session.rollback()

    @property
    def session(self):
        return self._session()

    def get_or_create(self, model, commit=True, **kwargs):
        instance = self.session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
        if instance:
            return instance, False
        else:
            instance = self.create(model, commit=commit, **kwargs)
            return instance, True

    def create(self, model, commit=True, **kwargs):
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        self.session.add(instance)
        if commit:
            self.session.commit()
        return instance
```

tests.py:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from unittest import TestCase

from models import Riders
from db import DB

class TestDBInteractions(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.temp_ = mkdtemp()
        cls.temp_db = os.path.join(cls.temp_, 'test_db.db')

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_uri = 'sqlite:///' + self.temp_db
        self.db = DB(self.db_uri)
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.temp_db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.db.close()

    def test_get_or_create(self):
        test_data = {
            'id': 1,
            'first_name': 'Bobby',
            'last_name': 'Hill',
            'cap_number': '123',
            'category': 'solo',
            'status': 'finished',
            'gender': 'male',
            'deposit_status': 'paid',
            'deposit_amount': 123.1,
            'email': 'hello@bob.com'
        }
        params = tuple(test_data.values())
        query = "INSERT INTO riders VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        self.cur.execute(query, params)
        # # sqlite doesn't allow multiple write connections to the same DB, so close this connection
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        self.db1 = DB(db_uri=self.db_uri)
        response = self.db1.get_or_create(Riders, **{'id': 1})
        print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Joined Table Inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance), SQLA does a wonderful job of letting you forget that there are even two tables in use.

Your test setup doesn't insert any data into `tracker_locations` as would be the case if you instantiated an instance of `Riders` and inserted the data through the ORM.

Here is the join part of the query that SQLA generates:

```
FROM tracker_locations JOIN riders ON tracker_locations.id = riders.id
```

In you test data set, there is no row in `tracker_locations`, so the join condition `tracker_locations.id = riders.id` doesn't evaluate true.

So, if you also include some test data in the `tracker_locations` table it will work:

```
tracker_locations_test_data = {'id': 1, 'type': 'riders'}
self.cur.execute(
    'INSERT INTO tracker_locations VALUES (?,?)', 
    tuple(tracker_locations_test_data.values()))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much. Good lesson learnt about looking at what SQL query SQLA executes. Have been stuck on this for far too long, I should've turned to stackoverflow much sooner. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, `echo=True` is a time saver!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqlite3` to manually loading data to the `riders` table only is not enough to honor the "Joined Inheritence" of the `Riders` model from the `TrackerLocations` Model. You have to fill also the correct data to the `TrackerLocations` for sqlalchemy to be able to use the information from the `Models` and make the correct lookup.

Use:

```
def test_get_or_create(self):
    test_data = {
        'id': 1,
        'first_name': 'Bobby',
        'last_name': 'Hill',
        'cap_number': '123',
        'category': 'solo',
        'status': 'finished',
        'gender': 'male',
        'deposit_status': 'paid',
        'deposit_amount': 123.1,
        'email': 'hello@bob.com'
    }
    test_tracker = {
        'id':1,
        'type':'riders'
    }
    params = tuple(test_data.values())
    query = "INSERT INTO riders VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    self.cur.execute(query, params)
    query = "INSERT INTO tracker_locations VALUES (?,?)"
    params = tuple(test_tracker.values())
    self.cur.execute(query, params)
    # # sqlite doesn't allow multiple write connections to the same DB, so close this connection
    self.conn.commit()
    self.conn.close()

    self.db1 = DB(db_uri=self.db_uri)

    response = self.db1.get_or_create(Riders, **{'id': 1})
    print(response)
```

for the test and it should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for the help, this was the correct approach as highlighted by yourself and SuperShoot. Only accepted their answer due to external links and detail re the SQL query. Thanks again